# Each Dropdown list in ReactJS Array Map share the same toggle boolean so they all open and close at the same time. How to make this work individually?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, toggle, dropdown

I have an array that for every item in the array a drop down list is dynamically generated. Right now each drop down list share the same toggle boolean so they all open and close at the same time, how can I make this work individually?

```
                    {/* ===== Display Your Team Begin Code ===== */}
                    {displayTeam.map((list, i) => (

                        <Card body outline style={{outlineColor: 'grey', backgroundColor:'#EBEBEB', width:'220px', float:'left', margin:'20px'}} key={i}>

                            <Row xs="2" md="2" sm="auto">
                                <CardTitle tag="h6"><b>{list.team}</b></CardTitle>

                                <div>
                                <ButtonDropdown style={{float:'right', backgroundImage:'../assets/TitikTiga.png', backgroundColor:'white', border:'0px'}} isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle1} sty>
                               
                                    <DropdownToggle style={{border:'0px', borderRadius:'0px', backgroundColor:'transparent'}}>
                                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEllipsisV} style={{color:'black'}}/>
                                    </DropdownToggle>
                                    <DropdownMenu>
                                        <DropdownItem onClick={modalToggleEditTeam}>Edit team</DropdownItem>
```

[Toggle boolean didn't work individually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2ivv.png)

Comment: Could you please paste the full version of your component here?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the unique-id of selected list into the state and check if

`isOpen={selectedUniqueId === currentId}`

Add few more code into the question to help you more specifically